# Remove Item from List of Lists

Tags: prolog

I have a list containing records which have an Id, name and gender. I am trying to have a user pass in either the Id (an integer) or name (a string), and removing that record, but it's not doing anything.

This is what i have:

```
choice(5,X) :-
    write('\tEnter an ID or Name:'),
    read(Item),
    rem(Item, X, X2),
    menu(X2).
```

and my remove is:

```
rem(Item, [], []) :- write("List is empty.").
rem(Item, [[Item,RT]|L],L).
rem(Item, [[ID, Item|PT]|L]|L).
rem(Item, [X|XT],[X|YT]) :- rem(Item, XT, YT).
```

But when i run it, it just gives me a list of integers.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is (almost) working fine.

You just had a typo in the third rule: you wrote a `|` instead of a `,`, and the prolog interpreter lets you know with:

```
Warning: user://1:18:
    Clauses of (rem)/3 are not together in the source-file
```

You may want to remove the write("List is empty."), because that rule non only matches when you try to remove an item from an empty list, but it is also the base case of the recursive delete. It prints numbers because you supply it with a string ("abc") instead of an atom ('abc'). Compare the result of `write('abc')` with the result of `write("abc")`.

Also, you need a cut in the removing rule, because if the item exists in the list, you want to remove it, and you are not interested in other solution arising from backtracking from that choice point.

```
rem(Item, [], []).
rem(Item, [[Item,RT]|L],L) :- !.
rem(Item, [[ID, Item|PT]|L],L) :- !.
rem(Item, [X|XT],[X|YT]) :- rem(Item, XT, YT).
```

Test:

```
?- rem(x, [[a,3],[b,4],[remove_me,x,6],[d,8]], X).
X = [[a, 3], [b, 4], [d, 8]].
```

Comment: It's good practise to test Prolog code for steadfastness when using `(!)/0`.

Answer (score 1):

May be I misunderstood the problem, but I think that

```
rem(Item, L_In, L_Out) :-
    select([Item|_], L_In,L_Out);select([_,Item|_], L_In, L_Out).
```

does the job.